# Getting this.style from a polymer element

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

Just learning polymer. I want to grab the color of fixed-header when it is clicked.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name="fixed-header" attributes="height" style="background-color:blue">
<template>
    <style>
        :host {
            display: block;
            background-color: red;
        }
        ::content * {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
    <header layout horizontal on-click="{{changeColor}}">
        <content select="li"></content>
    </header>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer('fixed-header', {
        changeColor: function() {
            var color = this.style.backgroundColor
            console.log(color)
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

When I don't use the inline style on polymer-element, I can't use this.style.backgroundColor, even though it is definitely changing color to be red. Why can't I use this.style.backgroundColor when it is just through the template style tag?

Also, I'm trying to set the backgroundColor, but I can't do that either.

Answer (score 1):

Returning an object representation of the contents of a node's `style` attribute is the [expected behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style#Summary) of the `style` property. What you want is [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
var color = getComputedStyle(this).backgroundColor;
```

Here's a [working jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ravuzuro/1/edit?html,output).

To your second comment, setting `style` [works fine](http://jsbin.com/ravuzuro/2/edit?html,output) for me in Chrome 36 and 38.